# Nested maximum function not working

Tags: function-construction, mathematical-optimization, maximum

I am trying to maximize a function which is itself a maximized function. For example, see the below.

Can someone explain this error:

```
Rev[p_, theta_, I_, a_, c1_] := theta*p*Min[I, a*p^c1]

V2ces[p_, theta_, I_, a_, c1_]  := 
 FindMaximum[{Rev[p, theta, I, a, c1]}, p]

VDPces[p_, theta_, I_, a_, c1_] := 
 Rev[p, theta, I, a, c1] + V2ces[p, theta, I, a, c1]

FindMaximum[VDPces[p, 1, 2, 2.5, -2], {p, 0.1, 5}]
```

Error:[image]

Answer (score 4):

From the [`FindMaximum`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindMaximum.html) documentation

> FindMaximum returns a list of the form `{fmax,{x->xmax,y->ymax,…}}`...

So `Rev[p, theta, I, a, c1] + V2ces[p, theta, I, a, c1]` tries to add together a scalar (from `Rev`) and a list that has the structure `{_, {...}}`, which isn't how addition works.

So I believe you actually want [`FindMaxValue`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindMaxValue.html) which returns the actual maximum value that's given in `FindMaximum`.

So basically change `V2ces` to

```
FindMaxValue[{Rev[p, theta, I, a, c1]}, p]
```

or

```
FindMaximum[{Rev[p, theta, I, a, c1]}, p][[1]]
```

and you get

```
FindMaximum[VDPces[p, 1, 2, 2.5, -2], {p, 0.1, 5}]
```

> {4.47214, {p -> 1.11803}}

albeit with the warning

> FindMaxValue::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to within the tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient increase in the function. You may need more than MachinePrecision digits of working precision to meet these tolerances. >>

Comment: Ah got it! I am fairly new to mathematica, thank you for this explanation!